# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' main.jar (Accesso negato)

Tags: java, debugging, jar

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\app_name\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\jars\2\1f\main.jar (Accesso negato)

This is the error that I have when I build the project.

Comment: Please give more context to your question and explain what you tried to solve the error. Thanks !

Comment: I search on line the way to solve the problem for many days and now for the last try I ask directly here...I found that I have to modify the grandle file but it doesn't work. I clean the project and rebuild it but it doesn't work

Comment: The funny staff is that there isn't the file main.jar into that folder so I can't understand why he says that he cannot access if that file doesn't exist